# EF рекурсивно получить плоский список всех детей в дереве

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть обьект в базе типа

```
class Node
{
public int Id
public int ParentId
public Node ParentNode
public IEnumerable<Node> Childrens
}
```

Нужно получить плоский список (массив) всех детей (и детей детей и т.д) ноды.

Comment: а как дерево представить в плоском виде? приведите пример данных и то что Вы хотите получить

Comment: Нужно не дерево, а список. В базе структура с Id и ParentId, нужно получить Id всех детей со всех уровней какой-то ноды

Comment: [так](http://blog.zwezdin.com/ru/101) попробуйте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте рекурсию с yield:

```
static IEnumerable<Node> LoadDescendants(Node node)
{
    foreach (Node child in node.Childrens)
    {
        yield return child;
        foreach (var childDescendant in LoadDescendants(child))
        {
            yield return childDescendant;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А оно все одним запросом подтянет или нет?

Comment: @sss скорее всего нет. EF не умеет делать иерархические запросы - у ORM вообще с этим туго (впрочем, могу ошибаться)